# charset and issue of special chars

Tags: php, html

I am having some issues charset and special chars in this page : http://goo.gl/UGgxWt
i have added in  my header section charset code :

```
<html lang="fr">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

i tried to add in the body section

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

nothing changed still the same problem , i went to htaccess file i added

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

but it didn't solved this issue can you help with a solution to that situation

Comment: You can say "I'm speaking french" as much as you want, but if you say it in english, then you're actually speaking english. If you know what I mean... and I mean that if your file is actually in (say) iso-8859-1, and your server is sending iso-8859-1 files, it doesn't matter what your header says: you're actually sending iso-8859-1 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this as well

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-8">
```

Comment: i tested all these scripts nothing made a change

Comment: @Guns_Roses check **edit 01**

Comment: thanks @Abdulla but i tested it it didn't work, no changes , i am using html 5 no conflict your script with that language ??

Comment: remove it.  and i check your site. But i cant find this kind of code in your `<head>` section. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-8">`

Comment: ok @Abdulla its done

Comment: working?? all `meta` content should place next to `head` tag

Comment: no brother its not working ..

Comment: again you missing  the `<meta>`

Comment: ok i corrected  the my script

Comment: @Guns_Roses now its working

Comment: @Guns_Roses don't forget to upload your font files too

Comment: no, for me its not working at all , now is worst , i am using firefox , i cleaned history /cash folder of the navigator

Comment: its working fine on my pc. chrome and firefox too.

Comment: thank you for your time and help now it works problem of encoding i rebuilt the page , it wasn't a problem of meta

Comment: @Guns_Roses happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your html output has not any problem.
Save your file in "utf-8 without BOM" encoding.

Comment: yes saved as yuou told me in "utf-8 without BOM" encoding. sorry still facing the same issue

Comment: Thank you Guys now it works problem of encoding i rebuilt the page , it wasn't a problem of meta

Comment: If it wasn't problem of meta is  my answer valid??!! @Guns_Roses

Answer (score 0):

try adding below meta tag, also make sure your .html file is in utf-8

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`